# Exporting profile data from Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, profile, orchardcms

I have a client requirement to be able to export user data from Orchard, specifically extended data fields from the user registration module ExtendedRegistration which uses the profile module.

I have access to the SQL CE db and can see the user registration data, but can't see where the profile data is stored, and no doubt am looking in completely the wrong place. Any ideas??

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a common table Orchard_FrameWork_ContentItemRecord that keeps an xml style record of data linked to ItemIDs coming from particular modules - the extended registration module included.  I can link to this using the user id as the primary key but I need to parse the data to report against it.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
<Data><User><StreetAddress>23jjj</StreetAddress><Postcode>3101</Postcode><State>vic</State></User></Data>
```

Got that figured - now to parse the data!

Answer (score 1):

Orchard names database tables after the module name and part record class name. 
Eg. a *MyPartRecord*, contained in *Contrib.MyModule* will be mapped to a table named **Contrib_MyModule_MyPartRecord**.

Look for the appropriate **[something]Record** class in a module's /Models folder and then look for the table using the naming convention I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks pszmyd - sorry for the no communicado - been in new caledonia on holidays.  was awesome.  your post made me have another look at it, indeed the data is there - not under the module name as expected though.  I've put the answer below - Thanks for looking at this.  I wanted to up your comment but I haven't got the rep. :(